# php5.6-fpm with Apache 2.4 displays php source on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: ubuntu, apache-2.4, php-fpm, ubuntu-14.04, php5

My Ubuntu Vagrant displays PHP source instead of interpreting PHP scripts. 
What am I doing wrong?

My apache.conf:

```
<Directory />
  Options FollowSymLinks
  AllowOverride None
</Directory>
```

My vhost config:
   
      ServerName kunstmaan.cms

```
  DocumentRoot "/var/www/logus/web"

  AllowOverride All
  Require all granted

  (...)
</Directory>
```

serve-cgi-bin.conf

```
<IfModule mod_alias.c>
    <IfModule mod_cgi.c>
            Define ENABLE_USR_LIB_CGI_BIN
    </IfModule>

    <IfModule mod_cgid.c>
            Define ENABLE_USR_LIB_CGI_BIN
    </IfModule>

    <IfDefine ENABLE_USR_LIB_CGI_BIN>
            ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /usr/lib/cgi-bin/
            <Directory "/usr/lib/cgi-bin">
                    AllowOverride None
                    Options +ExecCGI -MultiViews +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
                    Require all granted
            </Directory>
    </IfDefine>
</IfModule>
```

/etc/apache2/conf-enabled/php5-fpm.conf

```
<IfModule mod_fastcgi.c>
   AddHandler php5.fcgi .php
   Action php5.fcgi /php5.fcgi
   Alias /php5.fcgi /usr/lib/cgi-bin/php5.fcgi
   FastCgiExternalServer /usr/lib/cgi-bin/php5.fcgi -socket /var/run/php5-fpm.sock -pass-header Authorization -idle-timeout 3600
   <Directory /usr/lib/cgi-bin>
       Require all granted
   </Directory>
</IfModule>
```

cgi-bin directory is empty:

```
ls -la /usr/lib/cgi-bin/
total 8
drwxr-xr-x  2 www-data www-data 4096 Oct  6 12:29 ./
drwxr-xr-x 69 root     root     4096 Oct 12 00:10 ../
```

/etc/php5/fpm/pool.d/www.conf

```
user = www-data
group = www-data
...
listen = /var/run/php5-fpm.sock
listen.owner = www-data
listen.group = www-data
```

no socket in ls:

```
$ sudo ls -la /var/run/php5-fpm.sock
ls: cannot access /var/run/php5-fpm.sock: No such file or directory
```

I noticed I have 2 services: php5-fpm and php5.6-fpm and when I start the second one, it keep "start/running" state forever. I can stop it, it stays in "stop/waiting" state for a long time.

How do I fix this?

Comment: if there is no socket file , php-fpm is not running, read the logs from php5-fpm and find out where in the fpm pool configuration you have made a mistake.. or what really happens. One you get php-fpm up and running I would suggest going for mod_proxy_fcgi instead of a third party module like you are doing now. which would be as easy as adding three lines in your virtualhost `<FilesMatch "\.php$"> \ SetHandler  "proxy:unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock|fcgi://localhost/" \ </FilesMatch>`